# How to get an object from an array Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, arrays, object, ruby-on-rails-4, pluck

In controller I use pluck method to get id and name from my database

```
@user1 = User.where(name: 'Alex').pluck(:id, :name).first 
@user2 = User.where(name: 'Alex').pluck(:id, :name)
```

It return array

```
@user1 = `[3, 'Alex']` 
@user2 = [[3,'Alex'],[4, 'Alex']]
```

How can I make object from array, like:

```
@user1 = <User id:3, name:'Alex'> 
@user2 = [<User id:3, name:'Alex'>, <User id:4, name:'Alex'>]
```

Comment: Remove `pluck`, i.e. `@user1 = User.where(name: 'Alex').first`

Comment: @Stefan But pluck more faster then first

Comment: `pluck` is faster, because it doesn't instantiate the record. It's pointless if you are instantiating the record yourself afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
users = User.where(name: 'Alex').pluck(:id, :name).map do |id, name|
  User.new({ id: id, name: name })
end
```

Or from provided variables:

```
@user1_obj = User.new(id: @user1[0], name: @user1[1])
@user2_arr = @user2.map { |params| User.new(id: params[0], name: params[1]) }
```

Please, be advised, you should let ORM do the thing for you, rather building objects on your own.

Hope that helps!

Comment: But pluck return an array, not a hash. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: Ahh yes... I've been confused by code samples you've provided. I've just updated the answer!